# How to use the changed IndexerName in c# so that WPF elements also gets updated?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class with an indexer defined. As long as I keep the default IndexerName (Item) WPF elements update nicely.
e.g.

```
public byte this[int index] {
    get { return ListElements[index].Value; }
    set {
        ListElements[index].Value = value;
        FirePropertyChanged("Item[]");
    }
}
protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

In XAML I am binding it as follows

```
<Label Content="{Binding CurrentDevice[3]}"/>
```

As mentioned, this currently works nicely. However for better readability in the code (e.g. notify event handler method) I tried to change the original code to

```
[IndexerName("ElementItem")]
public byte this[int index] {
    get { return ListElements[index].Value; }
    set {
        ListElements[index].Value = value;
        FirePropertyChanged("ElementItem[]");
    }
}
```

The c# event handler method I provided recognized the change when checking for (e.PropertyName == "ElementItem[]") but WPF elements didn't.

Is there a way to get it working in WPF?

I even tried modifying the XAML binding to {Binding CurrentDevice.ElementItem[3]} without success. The initial element read at startup succeeded but afterwards the element did not display the new value.

Comment: The IndexerName attribute isn't meant to be set by application code. It "*indicates the name by which an indexer is known in programming languages that do not support indexers directly*". Just do not use it. Instead of increasing readability, it only creates confusion. On the MSDN page, they also say that "*the classes in System.Runtime.CompilerServices are for compiler writers use only*".

Comment: You can leave `FirePropertyChanged("Item[]");` even after applying `IndexerName` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The indexer binding will look for a property change of Item[], I don't think you can change this.

Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xtof/2007/09/28/binding-to-indexers/